# IL Harmor soundesign thread

Tags: synthesis, synthesizer

Anyone have tried this great plug-in?
How is your workflow? I'm still learning so your advice and suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Hey User 6915 Welcome to the Forum!
Harmor is a very interesting Synth. It can create a lot of crazy new sounds. 
The most important part about Harmor is, that you can apply effects and modulation to different frequency areas. For example: The higher the frequency, the higher the chorus amount, detune, distortion etc.

http://www.youtube.com/user/SeamlessR

The link is a portal to one of the biggest Harmor "freaks" in the web. He shows how to use Harmor to create up to date, Neurofunk, Dubstep and Electro sounds. In his tutorials he explains in depth how different parameters work. So its a worth watching, even if you do not like those sounds.

Peace

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Harmor for a few years now and I would NEVER go to anything else (except Sytrus for FM/RM synthesis). The realy amazing thing about Harmor is the additive/subtractive thing about the way it is made. You can draw filter shapes! You can create filter masks and extremely versatile mapping. You can fully customize the signal flow. The unison is pretty much THE best in the market and its built in distortion is to die for. The main UI is scary but the REAL power grows from it's 100 odd envelopes, LFOs, keyboard/velocity/x/y/z mapping etc.

SeamlessR is a youtuber that essentially is a Harmor guru. He posts loads of videos explaining how it works and what is possible in many episodes of hie "How to Bass" series. Image-Line also posted a video of a lecture he did at dancefair on Harmor where he explains it in some extreme depth and then you really start to get an idea of its true power.

In terms of use: Ignore the envelopes to start with. Open up the spectrum analyzer and mess around with EVERY parameter to figure out what it does more specifically. Only once you've got the basic idea should you start exploring what the envelopes can do as they can do a lot more than you would expect.

I spent about 2 weeks doing this and it's got to the point where you can mention something in sound design and I can get to it in Harmor in under 20 seconds.

Good luck learning how to use this as I wouldn't be surprised if, once you go down to the fundamental components of it, it's one of if not the most powerful synthesizer on the market to date.

Answer (score 0):

The harmonic setting on the phaser is excellent (next to the Oct, Hz setting), as long as its chained correctly it will really only let harmonics through. Its great for exciting timbres if you're using the Prism module because it normally pushes the partials of the sound very far apart from each other, which itself is great for in harmonic tones but gets a bit to 'side bandy' at the extremes.

I've also used the Image re synthesis engine to distort some voices rather than just pitching them down, you can set the form to neutral and get a very distinct robotic voice.

It's quite a deceptively simple looking synth but some of the routing and labeling isn't exactly clear, such as the Pluck module having a 'blur' button while the blur is actually on the other side of the plugin.

The filter is a lot more responsive than most subtractive synths because its just modulating the amplitude of the individual sines rather than actually filtering. Its also got quite a nice workflow with you being able to right click anything and choosing the edit articulator option rather than looking through the tables of envelopes.